# Is possible to install Oracle data guard free?

Tags: oracle, dataguard

I need to install an Oracle database and Oracle data guard. It's only for formation and education, no production or something like that.
I've saw Oracle Xe don't have these feature.
Is there some way to get that "free"?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Data Guard is part of Enterprise Edition.

You can download Enterprise Edition and use it for the purpose you mentioned according to the OTN license.

[Oracle Technology Network License Agreement](https://www.oracle.com/downloads/licenses/distribution-license.html)